# Use mouse wheel in Excel dynamic combobox not working on Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, mouse, mousewheel

I created a file with Excel 2016 and I saved as .xls as it must be able to be used by other computers in the enterprise with Excel 2003. Among other things there are combobox popup. I entered the codes that allow me to scroll through the data using the mouse wheel. Everything works perfectly on machines running Windows 10 and 64 bit Excel 2016, Excel 2003 and Windows 7 64bit, Windows XP 32bit and Excel 2003.
The problem arises when this file is opened on (more than one) PC with Windows 7 64bit and Excel 2010: when the user double-clicks on the affected cell (which should appear combobox) presents the error: "Error compilation: type mismatch. "

The error is on row 151, is highlighted "CallNextHookEx".

This is the entire module

```
Option Explicit

Private Type POINTAPI
  x As Long
  y As Long
End Type

Private Type MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    pt As POINTAPI
    mousedata As Long
    flags As Long
    time As Long
    dwExtraInfo As Long
End Type

#If VBA7 Then
    #If Win64 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong Lib "USER32" Alias "GetWindowLongPtrA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
    #Else
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong Lib "USER32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
    #End If
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "USER32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
    (ByVal Destination As LongPtr, _
    ByVal Source As LongPtr, _
    ByVal Length As LongPtr)

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" _
    Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib _
    "USER32" _
    Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" _
    (ByVal idHook As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpfn As LongPtr, _
    ByVal hmod As LongPtr, _
    ByVal dwThreadId As LongPtr) As LongPtr

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "USER32" _
    (ByVal hHook As LongPtr, _
    ByVal nCode As LongPtr, _
    ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
    lParam As Any) As LongPtr

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "USER32" _
    (ByVal hHook As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
    (ByVal Destination As Long, _
    ByVal Source As Long, _
    ByVal Length As Long)

    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" _
    Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

    Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib _
    "USER32" _
    Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" _
    (ByVal idHook As Long, _
    ByVal lpfn As Long, _
    ByVal hmod As Long, _
    ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "USER32" _
    (ByVal hHook As Long, _
    ByVal nCode As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    lParam As Any) As Long

    Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "USER32" _
    (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long
#End If


Private Const HC_ACTION = 0
Private Const WH_MOUSE_LL = 14
Private Const WM_MOUSEWHEEL = &H20A
Private Const GWL_HINSTANCE = (-6)

Private uParamStruct As MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
Private oObject As Object
Private lLowLevelMouse As Long
Private bHooked As Boolean

'====================='
'\\ Public Routines   '
'====================='

Public Property Let MakeScrollableWithMouseWheel _
(ByVal Obj As Object, ByVal vNewValue As Boolean)

    If vNewValue Then
        Hook_Mouse
    Else
        UnHook_Mouse
    End If

    Set oObject = Obj
    bHooked = vNewValue

End Property


Public Property Get MakeScrollableWithMouseWheel _
(ByVal Obj As Object) As Boolean

    MakeScrollableWithMouseWheel = bHooked

End Property



'====================='
'\\ Private Routines  '
'====================='
#If VBA7 Then
    Function LowLevelMouseProc _
    (ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

        Static iTopIndex As Integer

        On Error Resume Next

        If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
            If wParam = WM_MOUSEWHEEL Then
                With oObject
                    If GetHookStruct(lParam).mousedata > 0 Then
                        .TopIndex = iTopIndex - 1
                        iTopIndex = .TopIndex
                    Else
                        .TopIndex = iTopIndex + 1
                        iTopIndex = .TopIndex
                    End If
                End With
                LowLevelMouseProc = -1
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If

        LowLevelMouseProc = _
        CallNextHookEx(lLowLevelMouse, nCode, wParam, ByVal lParam)
#Else
 Function LowLevelMouseProc _
    (ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

        Static iTopIndex As Integer

        On Error Resume Next

        If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
            If wParam = WM_MOUSEWHEEL Then
                With oObject
                    If GetHookStruct(lParam).mousedata > 0 Then
                        .TopIndex = iTopIndex - 1
                        iTopIndex = .TopIndex
                    Else
                        .TopIndex = iTopIndex + 1
                        iTopIndex = .TopIndex
                    End If
                End With
                LowLevelMouseProc = -1
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If

        LowLevelMouseProc = _
        CallNextHookEx(lLowLevelMouse, nCode, wParam, ByVal lParam)
#End If
End Function

Private Function GetHookStruct(ByVal lParam As Long) As MSLLHOOKSTRUCT

   CopyMemory VarPtr(uParamStruct), lParam, LenB(uParamStruct)
   GetHookStruct = uParamStruct

End Function

Private Function GetAppInstance() As Long

    GetAppInstance = GetWindowLong _
    (FindWindow("XLMAIN", Application.Caption), GWL_HINSTANCE)

End Function

Private Sub Hook_Mouse()

    If lLowLevelMouse = 0 Then
        lLowLevelMouse = SetWindowsHookEx _
        (WH_MOUSE_LL, AddressOf LowLevelMouseProc, GetAppInstance, 0)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub UnHook_Mouse()

    If lLowLevelMouse <> 0 Then _
    UnhookWindowsHookEx lLowLevelMouse: lLowLevelMouse = 0

End Sub
```

This is the Sheet1 code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim str As String
Dim cboTemp As OLEObject
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim parola As String
Set WS = ActiveSheet
parola = "INDIRETTO"

Set cboTemp = WS.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
cboTemp.Activate
cboTemp.Visible = True
  On Error Resume Next
  With cboTemp
  'clear and hide the combo box
    .ListFillRange = ""
    .LinkedCell = ""
    .Visible = False
  End With
On Error GoTo errHandler
  If target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
    'if the cell contains
      'a data validation list
    Cancel = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    'get the data validation formula
    str = target.Validation.Formula1
    str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1)

    If InStr(str, parola) = 0 Then GoTo noindi
        str = Replace(str, "INDIRETTO(", "")     'Remove INDIRECT and opening parenthesis
        str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)           'Remove last closing parenthesis

        str = Evaluate(str)                     'Evaluate the formula to return named range
    End If
noindi:
    With cboTemp
      'show the combobox with the list
      .Visible = True
      .Left = target.Left
      .Top = target.Top
      .Width = target.Width + 5
      .Height = target.Height + 5
      .ListFillRange = str
      .LinkedCell = target.Address
    End With
    cboTemp.Activate
    'open the drop down list automatically
    Me.TempCombo.DropDown
    MakeScrollableWithMouseWheel(TempCombo) = True


errHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub

End Sub
'=========================================
Private Sub TempCOmbo_LostFocus()
MakeScrollableWithMouseWheel(TempCombo) = False
  With Me.TempCombo
    .Top = 10
    .Left = 10
    .Width = 0
    .ListFillRange = ""
    .LinkedCell = ""
    .Visible = False
    .Value = ""
  End With
End Sub

'====================================
'Optional code to move to next cell
'if Tab or Enter are pressed
'from code by Ted Lanham
'***NOTE: if KeyDown causes problems,
'change to KeyUp
'Table with numbers for other keys
'such as Right Arrow (39)
'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243025%28v=vs.60%29.aspx
'For dates or numbers in the data validation, you can use the KeyDown code in the Code for Numbers section below.

Private Sub TempCombo_KeyDown(ByVal _
     KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
     ByVal Shift As Integer)
  Select Case KeyCode
    Case 9 'Tab
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    Case 13 'Enter
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Case Else
        'do nothing
  End Select
End Sub
'====================================
'Private WithEvents wb As Workbook

'Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()
  '  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  ' MakeScrollableWithMouseWheel(TempCombo) = True
'End Sub

'Private Sub ComboBox1_LostFocus()
'    MakeScrollableWithMouseWheel(TempCombo) = False
'End Sub


'Private Sub wb_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  '  If MakeScrollableWithMouseWheel(TempCombo) Then
    '    MakeScrollableWithMouseWheel(TempCombo) = False
  '  End If
'End Sub
```

P.S.: all Office suites installed are 32bit

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problems after several attempts

this is the new module code

```
Option Explicit

Private Type POINTAPI
  x As Long
  y As Long
End Type

Private Type MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    pt As POINTAPI
    mousedata As Long
    flags As Long
    time As Long
    dwExtraInfo As Long
End Type

#If VBA7 Then
    #If Win64 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "USER32" Alias "GetWindowLongPtrA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
    #Else
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "USER32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
    #End If
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "USER32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
    (ByVal Destination As LongPtr, _
    ByVal Source As LongPtr, _
    ByVal Length As LongPtr)

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "USER32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As LongPtr, ByVal hmod As LongPtr, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As LongPtr


    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "USER32" (ByVal hHook As LongPtr, ByVal ncode As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "USER32" (ByVal hhk As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
    (ByVal Destination As Long, _
    ByVal Source As Long, _
    ByVal Length As Long)

    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" _
    Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

    Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib _
    "USER32" _
    Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" _
    (ByVal idHook As Long, _
    ByVal lpfn As Long, _
    ByVal hmod As Long, _
    ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "USER32" _
    (ByVal hHook As Long, _
    ByVal ncode As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    lParam As Any) As Long

    Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "USER32" _
    (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long
#End If


Private Const HC_ACTION = 0
Private Const WH_MOUSE_LL = 14
Private Const WM_MOUSEWHEEL = &H20A
Private Const GWL_HINSTANCE = (-6)

#If VBA7 Then
    Private hHook As LongPtr
#Else
    Private hHook As Long
#End If

Private uParamStruct As MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
Private oObject As Object
#If VBA7 Then
    Private lLowLevelMouse As LongPtr
#Else
    Private lLowLevelMouse As Long
#End If

Private bHooked As Boolean

'====================='
'\\ Public Routines   '
'====================='

Public Property Let MakeScrollableWithMouseWheel _
(ByVal Obj As Object, ByVal vNewValue As Boolean)

    If vNewValue Then
        Hook_Mouse
    Else
        UnHook_Mouse
    End If

    Set oObject = Obj
    bHooked = vNewValue

End Property


Public Property Get MakeScrollableWithMouseWheel _
(ByVal Obj As Object) As Boolean

    MakeScrollableWithMouseWheel = bHooked

End Property



'====================='
'\\ Private Routines  '
'====================='

#If VBA7 Then
Function LowLevelMouseProc _
    (ByVal ncode As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As Long) As LongPtr

        Static iTopIndex As Integer

        On Error Resume Next

        If (ncode = HC_ACTION) Then
            If wParam = WM_MOUSEWHEEL Then
                With oObject
                    If GetHookStruct(lParam).mousedata > 0 Then
                        .TopIndex = iTopIndex - 1
                        iTopIndex = .TopIndex
                    Else
                        .TopIndex = iTopIndex + 1
                        iTopIndex = .TopIndex
                    End If
                End With
                LowLevelMouseProc = -1
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If

        LowLevelMouseProc = _
        CallNextHookEx(lLowLevelMouse, ncode, wParam, ByVal lParam)


#Else
 Function LowLevelMouseProc _
    (ByVal ncode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

        Static iTopIndex As Integer

        On Error Resume Next

        If (ncode = HC_ACTION) Then
            If wParam = WM_MOUSEWHEEL Then
                With oObject
                    If GetHookStruct(lParam).mousedata > 0 Then
                        .TopIndex = iTopIndex - 1
                        iTopIndex = .TopIndex
                    Else
                        .TopIndex = iTopIndex + 1
                        iTopIndex = .TopIndex
                    End If
                End With
                LowLevelMouseProc = -1
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If

        LowLevelMouseProc = _
        CallNextHookEx(lLowLevelMouse, ncode, wParam, ByVal lParam)
#End If
End Function

Private Function GetHookStruct(ByVal lParam As Long) As MSLLHOOKSTRUCT

   CopyMemory VarPtr(uParamStruct), lParam, LenB(uParamStruct)
   GetHookStruct = uParamStruct

End Function
#If VBA7 Then
Private Function GetAppInstance() As LongPtr

    GetAppInstance = GetWindowLongPtr _
    (FindWindow("XLMAIN", Application.Caption), GWL_HINSTANCE)
#Else
    Private Function GetAppInstance() As Long

    GetAppInstance = GetWindowLongPtr _
    (FindWindow("XLMAIN", Application.Caption), GWL_HINSTANCE)
#End If

End Function

Private Sub Hook_Mouse()

    If lLowLevelMouse = 0 Then
        lLowLevelMouse = SetWindowsHookEx _
        (WH_MOUSE_LL, AddressOf LowLevelMouseProc, GetAppInstance, 0)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub UnHook_Mouse()

    If lLowLevelMouse <> 0 Then _
    UnhookWindowsHookEx lLowLevelMouse: lLowLevelMouse = 0

End Sub
```